# SSL Certificate Basic Constraints

Tags: encryption, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to learn more about certificates, and one of the things that I'm struggling to wrap my head around are the Basic Constraints. I was wondering if anyone that has experience working with certs could help me understand what the Basic Constrains are, how they work, and what they are used for.

I've tried doing my own research, and self educating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.9

> The basic constraints extension identifies whether the subject of the
> certificate is a CA and the maximum depth of valid certification
> paths that include this certificate.
>
> ...
>
> ```
>   BasicConstraints ::= SEQUENCE {
>    cA                      BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
>    pathLenConstraint       INTEGER (0..MAX) OPTIONAL }
> ```

It's just a marker of "is this certificate allowed to issue other certificates?" (cA:TRUE for yes, cA:FALSE for no).  When the answer is yes, it can optionally limit the number of tiers of "child CAs", 0 meaning the CA certificate isn't authorized to issue certificates that say cA:TRUE, 1 meaning the CA can issue certificates that say cA:TRUE, but those CAs can't, etc.

The technical questions about certs are answerable from [IETF RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280), or from [ITU-T X.509](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.509-201610-S/en) (from whence the name "X.509 certificate")

Comment: Thanks Bart that was actually very helpful. I'll read that documentation that you forwarded to me today!

Comment: Dear bartonjs, when the "cA" boolean is TRUE in the to-be-issued certificate, what is the point of limiting the number of "child CAs"? Does it mitigate any specific attack or increase security in anyway?

Comment: @EbrahimGhasemi Mostly it's to limit the risk to your "brand".  It's like the difference between giving your kid a credit card drawn on your account and giving your kid the permission to request cards at any time.  You may trust the kid to use the credit card, but don't trust them to make good decisions about letting OTHER people have credit cards on your account.  If that answer isn't sufficient, please ask a new question for it (probably on Security.SE).